# Why is x spacing different than y spacing in a tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to write a small simon says game using tkinter in python, but am having some spacing issues. In my code I create four buttons, one for each colour, and space them in different columns. Then, I create two labels, for borders to seperate the buttons. There is a horizontal label, and a vertical label. The code for the two labels is similar, with switches for height versus width, etc. Yet, I am finding the horizontal label displays as taller than the vertical label displays wide.

My code is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *


var = 100


def colour(col):
    print col


root = Tk()


for x in range(2 * var + 1):
    Grid.columnconfigure(root, x, weight=1, minsize=2)
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, x, weight=1, minsize=2)


red = Button(root, bg="RED", bd=0, relief=FLAT, command=lambda: colour("RED"))
red.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=var, columnspan=var, sticky=N+W+E+S)

blue = Button(root, bg="BLUE", bd=0, relief=FLAT, command=lambda: colour("BLUE"))
blue.grid(row=0, column=var+1, rowspan=var, columnspan=var, sticky=N+W+E+S)

green = Button(root, bg="GREEN", bd=0, relief=FLAT, command=lambda: colour("GREEN"))
green.grid(row=var+1, column=0, rowspan=var, columnspan=var, sticky=N+W+E+S)

yellow = Button(root, bg="YELLOW", bd=0, relief=FLAT, command=lambda: colour("YELLOW"))
yellow.grid(row=var+1, column=var+1, rowspan=var, columnspan=var, sticky=N+W+E+S)


border_vertical = Label(root, bg="BLACK")
border_vertical.grid(row=0, column=var, rowspan=2*var+1, columnspan=1, sticky=N+W+E+S)

border_horizontal = Label(root, bg="BLACK")
border_horizontal.grid(row=var, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=2*var+1, sticky=N+W+E+S)

# It seems that the horizontal line is starting and expanding thicker than the vertical line.
# The reason for this is unknown, as they are identical in code.

root.mainloop()
```

And here is [how it displays.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i3gY.png)

In the code I used a variable `var`, but that was just so I could figure out how large I wanted the window to be.

I've tried padding, which seemed to make the vertical border more like the horizontal border, but I would prefer if the horizontal border were more like the vertical border in attributes, because the vertical border scales similarly to the buttons, whereas the horizontal border seems to scale separately.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
border_vertical = Frame(root, bg="BLACK")
border_vertical.grid(row=0, column=var, rowspan=2*var+1, columnspan=1, sticky=N+W+E+S)

border_horizontal = Frame(root, bg = 'BLACK')
border_horizontal.grid(row=var, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=2*var+1, sticky=N+W+E+S)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Label` as a divider means it's going to have a height sufficient for text (even if there isn't any text in it). You can get the effect you want if you use a `Frame` instead.